next/image returning me bad request on local images
I have images in my public directory and when I try to reach them out, I get:

GET
http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=%2Fmedia%2Fheader-logo.png&w=256&q=75
400 (Bad Request)

The way I do it is:
<Image
      src="/media/header-logo.png"
      width={200}
      height={200}
      className="hidden md:block"
      alt="Logo"
    />

My file structure:

So I don't see why it cannot find my image. I event put in next.config.mjs:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    domains: ["localhost"],
  },
};

export default nextConfig;

UPDATE: I uploaded code in github and the clone it. After that images cannot be loaded.

For local development, you typically don’t need to specify localhost in the domains array. Here’s a simplified version of your next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: [],
  },
};

export default nextConfig;

try some alternative way clear the Next.js cache and restart the development server to ensure any changes take effect:
rm -rf .next
npm run dev


the domains configuration is outdated. Can you test remotePatterns instead of domains?
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        hostname: "localhost",
      },
    ],
  },
}


Still the same. 400 Bad Request

What version of nextjs and operating system do you have?

"next": "14.2.4",

And Linux, Mac, Windows?

Windows, sorry .

And are you cloning the repository to a folder located in the user's home directory or are you using WSL?

I clone the repo directly in user's home directory.

You can check if image if present on url or not.. by directly opening image in browser..
Visit: http://localhost:3000/media/header-logo.png
If image is loaded properly then issue is with next config.. otherwise issue is with public folder or image itself.

This would never work this way.

you are saying that http://localhost:3000/media/header-logo.png is not showing image on browser....
i'm asking to directly hit the image.. not to update in src

Next.js wont open images this way.

you can open any file.. pdf, html, png, svg this way if it's present in public folder

Issue can be due to the middleware. You may need to ignore these files in middleware.
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/((?!_next/static|_next/images|images|icons|favicon.ico|manifest.json).*)",
  ],
};

For local images, you can import the file and use it as src.
import logoMin from "../public/images/logo-min.png";

<Image
      src={logoMin}
      // width={200} // No need to specify width and height when src is imported
      // height={200}
      className="hidden md:block"
      alt="Logo"
    />

